# JNDI lookup of EJB deployed in same WAS instance

Tags: ejb, websphere, jndi

In my WAS, there are two EARs. The first EAR looks up an ejb that is packaged in the second ear. My question is, since the two EARs are in the same WAS, do we still need to supply the property `java.naming.provider.url as 'iiop://localhost:9810'` or will the server locate the EJB automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to.

If you don't specify it will look at the local Naming Server where both the EARs are running.

HTH

Manglu